# vim: shortcut to resize split windows

Tags: linux, vim, split, terminal, remap

When I have split windows in Vim, I can resize the windows using `:resize +1/-1`. I wanted to add a shortcut for it that worked like split windows in [terminator](https://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator). In terminator, if I have two windows on top of each other, `CTRL Shift Up` / `Down` moves the separator between the two windows, meaning, if I'm in the top window and press `CTRL Shift Down`, the top window increases. On the other hand, if I'm in the bottom window, `CTRL Shift Down` decreases the bottom window. So, it truly moves the separator.

With split windows in vim, I tried to remap like this:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <c-Up> :resize -1<CR>
:nnoremap <silent> <c-Down> :resize +1<CR>
```

This works fine if I'm on the top window (pressing `CTRL UP` decreases the size of the window and `CTRL Down` increases the size). But when I move to the bottom window it behaves correctly but it has a weird effect (`CTRL UP` also decreases the size of the window). So, I can't simulate moving the separator.

Is it possible o run a command depending on which window I'm located at?

Comment: There are definitely builtins: `<C-w>` and any of `<,>,+,-`

Comment: Maybe because there are differences between `:resize` and `:vertical resize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function in .vimrc

```
function! MoveSeparator(PlusMinus)
    let num=tabpagewinnr(tabpagenr())
    let pm=a:PlusMinus
    if  num == "2"
        let pm = pm == '+' ? '-' : '+'
    end
    exec "resize " . pm . "1"
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-UP>   :call MoveSeparator("-")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-DOWN> :call MoveSeparator("+")<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly if I have only two windows. But the moment I add one more, things go crazy. I'm not very familiar with this "vim language" but I will try to work on it using `winlayout()`, `win_id2tabwin()` and `:<winnr>resize`. But first I will have to learn about these vim syntaxes, but your function was already a start for me, thanks.

Comment: Right.—-— Done.

Answer (score 4):

Your code wasn't that wrong just needed a little changes.
Now you can resize all the panes in both **horizontal** and **vertical** way:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <c-Up> :resize -1<CR>
:nnoremap <silent> <c-Down> :resize +1<CR>
:nnoremap <silent> <c-left> :vertical resize -1<CR>
:nnoremap <silent> <c-right> :vertical resize +1<CR>
```